# Removing item from cart Redux, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

It does not delete the selected item. When I add it is everything ok. My cart has everything when I add. In the console, it tells me what I am deleting but does not remove.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = []

export const addItem = createAction('ADD_ITEM')
export const removeItem = createAction('REMOVE_ITEM')

export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [addItem.type]: (state, action) => [...state, action.payload],
  [removeItem.type]: (state, action) => state.filter(item => item !== action.payload)
})
```

```
function removeItemCart(item){
    dispatch(removeItem(item))
  }
```

Comment: Can't say why but a good start is to remove the item by ID not by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are comparing two object on the `filter` function, it will not work. Try to use object's property like `id`

```js
state.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)
```

Comment: Thank you. that was pretty much it